# Is there a smart and universal solution for using datatables.js with relational SQL table

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, phalcon

Couple of days I'm trying to build server side processing table grid with datatables.js and relational SQL table.

What that means ?

I have master table (with few JOINS), example

```
SELECT 
    m.id, 
    m.date, 
    u.name, 
    t.name,
    CASE m.type WHEN 1 THEN 'some value 1' WHEN 2 THEN 'some value 2' END
FROM master AS m
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON m.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN test AS t ON m.test_id = t.id
....
```

Everything is ok, but the main problem appears on searching etc...
First of all, I can decide how to store data into JSON for datatables, accessing with field names or with table prefix + field names

```
$(".dt").DataTable({
   "bServerSide": true,
   "sAjaxSource": "/items/show",
   "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
   columns: [
       { data: "m.id" },
       { data: "m.date" },
       { data: "m.type" },
    etc ....
});
```

That's ok, but when I try to search some values for type field I must write the whole procedure for processing "sSearch", "sSearch_0", "sSearch_1" ... "mField_1", "mField_2", etc ... We all well know, programmers are lazy sort of people and we like to make something non-repetitive and intuitive and something that can be used more than once.

That's not a problem, but this is not unique task so I can write code and fertig!, there are more situations where this must be used, same scenarios etc...

I'm wondering is there a something better than this, because I'm using datatables for admin backend in portal but I find it's a beast with single table (Users, Rules, Topics... etc.) This is really complex solution and I'm interested in your solutions for such a problems.

Is there a different solution for this type of tasks besides datatables plugin.

Problems like this can be done with datatables but in variant to put data in DOM, so

```
<tr>
foreach( records as rec )
    <td>rec->id</td>
    <td>rec->name</td>
    if bla bla bla
       <td>some value</td>
    ...
    etc ...   
</tr>
```

and then initialise datatables on this table object. Search is now locally in DOM and everything is ok. This is great solution for small amount of data, but I must handle 1.000.000 or more rows and because of that I'm choosing "server side processing".

Thanks

Comment: There is a list of ready serverside scripts here -> **https://datatables.net/development/server-side/** if you have special needs, you just take one of the scripts - python, php, node.js or whatever and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Yes, but with single table... and that work perfect! As I explain above :) Thanks for response anyway